# MySQL: ORDER BY ignored on joins?

Tags: mysql, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title AS label, m.url, img.filename, img.set_id,
m.keywords AS meta_keywords, m.keywords_overwrite AS meta_keywords_overwrite,
m.description AS meta_description, m.description_overwrite AS meta_description_overwrite,
m.title AS meta_title, m.title_overwrite AS meta_title_overwrite, m.data AS meta_data
FROM photogallery_categories AS c
INNER JOIN photogallery_categories_albums AS ca ON ca.category_id = c.id
INNER JOIN photogallery_albums AS i ON i.id = ca.album_id
INNER JOIN photogallery_sets_images AS img ON i.set_id = img.set_id
INNER JOIN meta AS m ON m.id = c.meta_id
WHERE c.language = ? AND i.hidden = ? AND i.publish_on <= ?  AND i.num_images > 0
GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY i.sequence DESC, img.sequence DESC
```

But my ORDER BY is completely ignored?
Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure? This shouldn't happen, I don't see any reason why the result wouldn't be sorted. Maybe you're misinterpreting the outcome...

Comment: Start with SELECT i.sequence, img.sequence, .... and post output

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the **i.sequence** to the field list.   Also, why are you using GROUP BY, since you are not including any aggregate functions?   Can you use DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY?